# update using self join not returning the results I am looking for

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi all I need to do a self join that doesn't include the null value.

Create the table:

```html
CREATE TABLE t2 (
        col1 varchar(255),
        col2 varchar(255),
        col3 varchar(255),
        col4 varchar(255),
        col5 varchar(255),
        col6 varchar(255)
    );

--Populate the table:

    INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
    VALUES
    ('1', '', 'new1', 'name1','',''),
    ('2', '', 'new2', 'name2','oldvalue1',''),
    ('3', '', 'new3', 'name3','',''),
    ('4', 'value1', 'new4', 'name4','','')
    ;

--Resulting in:

    | col1 |  col2  | col3 | col4  |    col5   | col6 | 
    | 1    |        | new1 | name1 |           |      |
    | 2    |        | new1 | name1 | oldvalue1 |      |
    | 3    |        | new1 | name1 |           |      |
    | 4    | value1 | new1 | name1 |           |      |
```

My update:

update t2 AS A, t2 AS B
set A.col6 = B.col3
where B.col5 = A.col2;

But the result is:

```html
    | col1 |  col2  | col3 | col4  |    col5   | col6 | 
    | 1    |        | new1 | name1 |           | new1 |
    | 2    |        | new1 | name1 | oldvalue1 | new1 |
    | 3    |        | new1 | name1 |           | new1 |
    | 4    | value1 | new1 | name1 |           |      |
```

What I want is:

```html
| col1 |  col2  | col3 | col4  |    col5   | col6 | 
| 1    |        | new1 | name1 |           |      |
| 2    |        | new1 | name1 | oldvalue1 | new1 |
| 3    |        | new1 | name1 |           |      |
| 4    | value1 | new1 | name1 |           |      |
```

what am I doing wrong?

I am using myspql and sequelpro on a mac

Thanks!

Comment: Without concrete and distinguishable values, your question is very cryptic.

Comment: @Uueerdo Hi sorry I tried to ask my question in a better way showing examples. what can i do to make this more legible I don't want to waste your time and still learning... thanks for your patience

Comment: 'oldvalue1' != 'value1', the problem with this kind of "join" update is you have multiple row matches the values could be pull from. The main issue with your original query vs expected results is you are expecting the col5 "match" to have it's col6 set; despite them being for different aliases/references to the table.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks! do you have time to provide an example so i can learn from it?

Comment: I simply cannot figure out the logic that you are trying to implement.  My first guess is that the self join is unnecessary.

Comment: All you should need to do is swap your SET expression around, and from the sample data (and assumptions about what it meant to say) should be predictable; you just need to consider what the _various_ possible results would have been with your original query if every record had a different col3 value.

Comment: I was trying to simplify things but I guess I screwed up. col2 will have different values on each row. cole 3 will have different values on each row. the values on col2 and the values on col5 will match. I am trying to put the value of col3 into col6 when col2 and 5 match. does that make more sense? please forgive a noob!

Answer (score 0):

did you try that ?

update b
set b.col6=a.col3
from t2 a 
    inner join t2 b on b.col5 = a.col2

Comment: thanks but i get an error when i try that:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from t2 a inner join t2 b on b.col5 = a.col2' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. I figured out what my issue was. in the table the null cess were just blank they didn't contain "NULL" in them. once i updated the table to have "NULL" in the blank cells then everything worked. thanks again for helping me on my sql journey.